# How split a QString and and save a part of string in a float's vector

Tags: c++, qt, vector, split

I use C++ in QT!!!
I have a string that contains some value that i have to save in a two float's vector.
The values that have to save in the first vector are separate with a ';' character and after a values that have to save in the second vector there is ':' character.
So I need to detect where are the delimiter character and save in the first float's vector the character between ':' and ';' and in the second vector the character between ':' and ';'

Can you help me?

Example of my QString:  10;2:56;12:10;89:

Vector that I would want:  first:10,56,10
                           second:2,12,89

Comment: If anyone else does your job, what do you contribute? Are you going to pay for it?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to split them via .split method of QString, the result of split method is a QStringList object, then you can accessing splited literals with .at(N) method.
After accessing first number group, you have to split them again and finaly accessing each part individually. .at(N) method returns a 
QString so you have to convert it to float via .toFloat() method

```
QString str = "10;2:56;12:10;89:";
QStringList strSplited = str.split(':');
QString numberGroup = strSplited.at(0);
float ac = numberGroup.split(';').at(0).toFloat();
float bc = numberGroup.split(';').at(1).toFloat();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I try it now!! :)